# Failed to fetch platform cordova-android

Tags: android, windows, cordova, command-line-interface

I just installed the new nodejs and cordova but cannot able to add android platform

```
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  android ~7.1.1
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~6.0.0
```

***here the error i am getting***

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~7.1.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

npm -version
**6.4.1**

cordova -version
**8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Windows usually this kind of error happens when you don't have all the paths required in your system environment path variable .
Especially the path variables given bellow.

Please paste this line on your system environment Path variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32;
```

Then close the current cmd and open a new cmd